In-memory & Client Side Caching
I am trying to check how the caching works in in-memory and client side using .NET 7.0. For in-memory caching, I keep the results from database in a cached object and when the object expires it fetches data from database again. So I did something as follows:
[HttpGet]
[Route("/user/GetUsers")]
public async Task<List<User>> GetUserDetails()
{
    myStopWatch.Start();
    Task<List<User>> users = GetCachedResponse(CacheKey.users, () => _user.GetUsers());
    myStopWatch.Stop();

    double total = myStopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

    return await users;
}

private async Task<List<User>> GetCachedResponse(string cacheKey, Func<Task<List<User>>> func)
{
    List<User> users = new List<User>();

    try
    {
        users = _cacheProvider.GetFromCache<List<User>>(cacheKey);
        if (users != null) return users;

        users = await func();

        _cacheProvider.SetCache(cacheKey, users, cacheEntryOptions);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }

    return users;
}

For client caching, I did the following to test:
[HttpGet]
[Route("/user/GetAllUsers")]
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "UserCacheForOneMin")]
public async Task<List<User>> GetAllUsers()
{
    myStopWatch.Start();
    Task<List<User>> users = _user.GetUsers();
    myStopWatch.Stop();

    double total = myStopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

    return await users;
}

I am not sure about the above as it didn't store the data in a cached object, but I did some configuration in the Startup.cs file as follows for response / client caching.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.CacheProfiles.Add("UserCacheForOneMin",
            new CacheProfile()
            {
                Duration = 60,
                Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Client
            });
    });
}
    
public void Configure(WebApplication app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseResponseCaching();
}

Finally when I run the app, I see the differences as follows;

Even though the client caching loads data faster, I would like to know how it actually works under the hood without separate storage or similar and am I doing the right thing here?
N.B: For in-memory, if a new record is added to the database, the cache object loads only the cached data until the expiration takes place. Later on expiration, it shows the data with the newly added one. But client / response caching, it checks for data in the database each time with the response time less than the in-memory caching. The image on the left is for client / response caching, the right one is for the in-memory caching.
Update 1: According to the comment of freakish - Correct measure using StopWatch class
[HttpGet]
[Route("/user/GetAllUsers")]
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "UserCacheForOneMin")]
public async Task<List<User>> GetAllUsers() 
{
  myStopWatch.Start();
  var users = await _user.GetUsers();
  myStopWatch.Stop();

  double total = myStopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

  return users;
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("/user/GetUsers")]
public async Task<List<User>> GetUserDetails() 
{
  myStopWatch.Start();
  var users = await GetCachedResponse(CacheKey.users, () => _user.GetUsers());
  myStopWatch.Stop();

  double total = myStopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;

  return users;
}


When ASP.NET sees ResponseCache attribute, then it will set appropriate cache headers on the HTTP response. It is then browsers responsibility to cache the response in its own local storage. And so the next time you make the request, it won't go to the server at all. Also, your myStopWatch measurements should cover await as well. At the moment you measure time to build Task object. That is likely to be irrelevant.

As .NET 7 is end of life, you would be better focused on updating to .NET 8 which will also bring its own set of performance improvements.

This is the server call - Task<List> users = _user.GetUsers();. I was expecting it shouldn't go to this line if cached, but in each request the debugger hits this line of code @freakish. How can I assign await to measure time with stop watch, any example?

Side note: this would be a good match for HybridCache, which is being released in .NET 9, but which targets down-level TFMs too (available in preview 4)

Updated the measure for await as well @freakish, I think that would be fine. Is there anything that I missed for response cache as it always hits the server-side?

@AT-2017: Having dev tools open usually disables client-side caching on the browser. Is the server hit multiple times if you close the browser dev tools?
